# Efficiently creating observables that filter a specific item from an observable collection

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a RxJS subject that publishes changes to a collection. Each time the collection changes, the subject publishes the new contents as an array. E.g.

```
let collectionSubject = new Rx.BehaviourSubject();

collectionSubject.onNext([{
    id: 1
}]);
```

I want to provide the ability for client code to subscribe to this collection on ‘by id’ basis. E.g. when the collection changes, they receive only the item that matches the queried id, if it is present. If the item isn't present, or has just been removed, they receive undefined.

I could naïvely implement this as follows:

```
byId(id) {
   return collectionSubject.filter(items => items.find(item => item.id == id));
}
```

However, this will create a new observable each time, and result in multiple redundant iterations of the items array. I could use a Map, keyed by id, to cache observables for a particularly id, but this would still result in multiple iterations of the items array for different ids.

The only solution I can see is to write a lot of custom machinery to create and cache and destroy subjects for each id, to iterate the collection once when it changes, and publish each item to any corresponding subject.

Is there a simpler, more idiomatic way to achieve this using the underlying RxJS operators? The key requirement is to only iterate the underlying collection a single time.

Comment: cf. http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/groupby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the link passed led you to an actual solution, so I give more details here about a possible approach. The idea is to use the operator `groupBy`, cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupby.md , http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html for the marbles and if you fancy here for the tests specs https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/spec/operators/groupBy-spec.js).

Supposing you have a map of observers by ids, called `observers`, you could try something along the lines :

```
collectionSubject = new Rx.Subject();
observers = [0, emits("observer for group 1"), emits("observer for group 2")];

collectionSubject
    .concatMap(function ( arr ) {return arr;})
    .tap(emits("tap"))
    .groupBy(function ( item ) {return item.id;})
    .subscribe(function ( groupObs ) {
                 groupObs.subscribe(function ( item ) {
                   observers[item.id](item);
                 });
               });

collectionSubject.onNext([
  {id : 1, value : "first item / group 1"},
  {id : 1, value : "second item / group 1"},
  {id : 2, value : "first item / group 2"},
  {id : 2, value : "second item / group 2"},
  {id : 1, value : "third item / group 1"},
  {id : 2, value : "third item / group 2"},
]);
```

test results here:

```
"tap emits first item / group 1"
"observer for group 1 emits first item / group 1"
"tap emits second item / group 1"
"observer for group 1 emits second item / group 1"
"tap emits first item / group 2"
"observer for group 2 emits first item / group 2"
"tap emits second item / group 2"
"observer for group 2 emits second item / group 2"
"tap emits third item / group 1"
"observer for group 1 emits third item / group 1"
"tap emits third item / group 2"
"observer for group 2 emits third item / group 2"
```

jsbin here.
https://jsbin.com/qikamamohi/edit?js,console

NOTE:

- the `concatMap` is a trick to emit the array content item by item and in order