# Cache state in Map of RxJS Subjects by id in Angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a collection of widgets for each `ownerId`. I am trying to cache the state of these collections in an Angular service by using a `Map<string, ReplaySubject<Widget[]>>`.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WidgetService {

    private readonly widgetsByOwnerId: Map<string, ReplaySubject<Widget[]>> =
        new Map<string, ReplaySubject<Widget[]>>();

    constructor(
        private readonly httpClient: HttpClient
    ) {}

    getWidgets(ownerId: string): Observable<Widget[]> {
        if (!this.widgetsByOwnerId.has(ownerId)) {
            const widgets$ = this.httpClient.get<Widget[]>(`api/${ownerId}/widgets`);
            const widgetsCache$ = new ReplaySubject<Widget[]>(1);
            widgets$.subscribe(widgetsCache$);
            this.widgetsById.set(ownerId, widgetsCache$);
        }
        return this.widgetsById.get(ownerId).asObservable();
    }

    createWidget(widget: Widget): Observable<Widget> {
        return this.httpClient
            .post<Widget>(`api/${widget.ownerId}/widgets`, widget)
            .pipe(
                tap((createdWidget): void => {
                    this.widgetsByOwnerId.forEach((widgets$, ownerId) =>
                        widgets$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
                            next: (widgets: Widget[]) => {
                                if(createdWidget.ownerId == ownerId || isOwnedById) {
                                    widgets.push(createdWidget);
                                    widgets$.next(widgets);
                                }
                            },
                        })
                    );
                }
            );
    }

    //additional CRUD functions excluded for brevity
}
```

Some special types of widgets can be owned by multiple widget owners, so some of the CRUD functions in the `WidgetService` can `next()` on multiple `ownerId`'s `ReplaySubject`s. In the sample above, I omitted some of this logic for brevity using `isOwnedById`.

A consumer of this service looks like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-widgets',
    templateUrl: './widgets.component.html',
})
export class WidgetsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    widgets: Widget[];

    private readonly ngUnsubscribe$: Subject<unknown> = new Subject();

    constructor(
        private readonly widgetService: WidgetService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const ownerId = this.getOwnerId();
        this.getWidgets(ownerId);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe$.complete();
    }

    private getOwnerId(): string {
        ...
    }

    private getWidgets(ownerId: string): void {
        this.widgetService
            .getWidgets(ownerId)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
            .subscribe({
                // TODO: this next is called once when first subscribed, but not when future widgets are created
                next: (widgets) => {
                    this.widgets = widgets;
                },
            });
    }

}
```

For some reason, when the consuming component first initializes, it gets the cached `Widget[]` successfully. However, when CRUD operations like `WidgetService.createWidget()` execute in other components (while the instance of `WidgetComponent` remains alive, e.g. before `WidgetComponent.ngOnDestroy()`), this `WidgetComponent` consumer never receives the `next()`-ed updates (as noted in the `TODO` comment).

Any suggestions for how to solve this so that consumers continue to get fed updates from the `WidgetService`'s `ReplaySubject`s? Thanks.

This question is kind of similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33496027/2343739), but different enough that I was not able to figure out how to adapt their answer to this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue here in these lines:

```
 const widgets$ = this.httpClient.get<Widget[]>(`api/${ownerId}/widgets`);
 const widgetsCache$ = new ReplaySubject<Widget[]>(1);
 widgets$.subscribe(widgetsCache$);
```

`httpClient` create a finity Observable meaning that it will be completed once request finishes or fails.

As a result your `ReplaySubject` passed as `Observer` to `subscribe` method will be completed and you won't get any events anymore.

To fix it you can replace `subscribe` implementation with the following:

```
widgets$.subscribe(res => widgetsCache$.next(res));
```